# UISearchResultsUpdating with custom class

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I am implementing `UISearchResultsUpdating` in Swift and what I am trying to do is:

1) I have a `NSMutableArray` filled with objects of type `MKSchool`.

2) `MKSchool` is of type `NSObject` and has three properties (`name`, `id`, `url`).

3) I want to filter the `tableView` based on `MKSchool.name`.

So far I have this implementation:

```
var schools: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var filteredSchools: NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()

func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        // Do something.
        filteredSchools.removeAllObjects()

        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)
        let array = schools.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    }
```

Now I receive this error: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 11 beyond bounds for empty array'.
I automatically assume this has to do with me not setting the updated array for`filteredSchools`, but I am not sure if I am doing the filtering right and how I should set the filteredSchools array.

Please help me by answering those 2 questions above.